# How to change type from object to nested in Elasticsearch 1.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Currently, my mapping looks like this.

```
hal: {
    properties: {
        debug: {
            type: "string",
            fields: {
                raw: {
                    type: "string",
                    index: "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        label: {
            type: "string",
            fields: {
                raw: {
                    type: "string",
                    index: "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        score: {
            type: "double"
        },
        sentiment: {
            type: "double"
        },
        type: {
            type: "string",
            index: "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
},
```

But from my research I need it to be type `nested` otherwise I can't use the combination of `term` and `range` as the element is flatten. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to change the type of mapping.

How do I do that? I'm using JavaScript elasticsearch npm module.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I haven't solved this. But I reindexed my whole cluster instead.

Comment: I found out that you cannot change mapping without deleting documents. You can add fields, but you cannot modify existing fields to a different type